# How to import Tkinter in python 3.3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I run python version 3.3.0 and when to try to `import Tkinter` in command window, I get this type of error:

```
>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import Tkinter
ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'
>>>
```

Please help me out how to solve this problem.

Comment: What about `import tkinter`?

Answer (score 6):

You should use tkinter with first letter "t" must be lower case-sensitive 
for Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

The name changed in Python 3.  Try `tkinter` with a lowercase 't'.

Many modules were renamed, modified, or forked when Python moved from 2.x to 3.x.  I like to use

```
>>> help('modules')
```

to see a list of current module names.  This works in all versions.